# matlab regexprep replace nth occurence

Tags: regex, matlab

Matlab documentation states that it is possible to replace the Nth occurrence of the pattern in regexprep. I am failing to see how to implement it and google is not returning anything useful.

http://www.weizmann.ac.il/matlab/techdoc/ref/regexprep.html

Basically the string I have is :,:,1 and I want to replace the second occurrence of : with an arbitrary number. Based on the documentation:

```
regexprep(':,:,4',':','AnyNumber','N')
```

I do no understand how the N option should be used. I have tried 'N',2 or just '2'.

Note that the position of the : could be anywhere.

I realize there are other ways of doing this other than regexprep but I don't like having a problem linger.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which version do you use? check `help regexprep`, maybe it's version dependend?! I use octave and can't use this special option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
regexprep(':,:,4',':','AnyNumber',2)
```

The above works.

Comment: If the you know the format of the string to be fixed, you could for example do: `s=':,:,4'; s(3)='9';` no regular expressions involved

Comment: Like I said, there are plenty of ways of doing the above task. Your method is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

According the MATLAB documentation, the general syntax of regexprep is:

```
newStr = regexprep(str,expression,replace,option1,...optionM);
```

It looks in the "str", finds matching "expression", and replaces the matching string with "replace". There are 9 available options. Eight of them are fixed strings, one is an integer. The integer tells which one of the matching string to be replaced.
The following code set up all the parameters as variables, find the number of the matching strings, and use that information to replace only the last occurrence.

```
str = ':,:,4'; 
expression= ':';
replace = num2str(floor(rand()*10)); 
                               % generate a single digit random number converted to string
idx = regexp(str, expression); % use regexp to find the number of matches
regexprep(str, expression, replace, length(idx)); % only replace the last one
```

Comment: Please explain your answer -- code-only answers may be hard for people to use

Comment: Kai, your question is addressed with new edits in the answer.